# Monero GUI will not build on Debian 8

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, build

Git cloned `monero-core`, installed the required dependencies.

Running `./build.sh` yields:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwallet_merged
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lepee
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -leasylogging
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:367: recipe for target 'release/bin/monero-wallet-gui' failed
make: *** [release/bin/monero-wallet-gui] Error 1
```

I then tried changing `monero-wallet-gui.pro` to include the contrib directory:

```
INCLUDEPATH +=  $$WALLET_ROOT/include \
                $$PWD/src/libwalletqt \
                $$PWD/src/QR-Code-generator \
                $$PWD/src \
                $$WALLET_ROOT/contrib \
                $$WALLET_ROOT/src
```

Since the libraries it cannot find, are in the contrib directory. Still errors.

- Debian 8 64bit
- Qt 5.9.2
- cmake version 3.0.2
- gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)

I'm guessing this is some sort of include or `$PATH` error, as it cannot seem to import these libraries. Any ideas?

Edit: apart from not being able to build via `build.sh`, it also does not build via QtCreator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error was **not** related to the importing/including of libraries, instead I encountered some unrelated build errors which I fixed by making sure I had GCC 5, G++ 5 and the latest cmake versions.

Answer (score 2):

Monero will be built only if GCC 5 and G++ 5 are installed in your system.